# C Unix program won't read from file

Tags: c, unix

I have a basic program that opens a file contained in the same directory as the C file (in root). The file is called `myfile1`, which is a simple file containing text.

This program is supposed to open the file, count the number of characters and display it. For some reason, I compile the program, run it with `a.out` and the program gets input from the user and finishes when <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is pressed, when it is supposed to get input from the file.

Any ideas as to what could be going on? Thank you very much, here is what I have so far:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
void main(){
char buff[512];
int fd = 0;
int j=0;
long total=0;

if(fd=open("myfile1",O_RDONLY)<0){
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
}
while((j=read(fd,buff,512))>0)
    total = total+j;
printf("%d\n",total);
close(fd);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: no `#include <stdio.h>`? It compiles? `void main()` and `return 0`?

Comment: yes I compiled it in the Unix environment with gcc timeBuff.c and it gives me the a.out file

Comment: You should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g timeBuff.c -o mytest` and you should use `perror` on failure. You are missing several `#include`-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your `if` condition: `fd=open("myfile1",O_RDONLY)<0`. Less-than comparison have higher precedence than assignment. It should be `(fd=open("myfile1",O_RDONLY))<0`.

Comment: So `fd` is assigned "false" or 0 since the open() call worked and returned 0. 0 happens to be the file descriptor for stdin.

Comment: you are correct. I fixed that part and it worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In your code, as ketlat said, the `if` logic is problematic.

If you put a debug print inside your code and check the `fd`,  you'll see

Code:

```
if(fd=open("myfile1",O_RDONLY)<0){
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
}
printf("obtained fd = %d\n", fd);
```

O/P:

> obtained fd = 0

**Reason**

`<` has higher preceidence over `=`. Hence, when the `open()` is success, it will return a non-negative value, which is not less than 0, and the comparison `open("myfile1",O_RDONLY)<0` will evaluate to *false* , represented as 0, and the same will be assigned to `fd`.

Nw, this `fd` value will be used in your `read()` call. FD 0 means `stdin` or the standard input. So, as per your logic, the code behaves correctly.

However, to achieve your goal, you need to change

```
fd=open("myfile1",O_RDONLY)<0
```

to

```
(fd=open("myfile1",O_RDONLY))<0
```

With the changed code, a sample run is likely to yield an o/p like

> obtained fd = 3.

Be notified, YMMV.